# ComponentWillMount() not invoked on android device

Tags: android, react-native

Absolute beginner at React-native on android. and here is my first hurdle.

why ComponentWillMount() method is not invoked after render() method. testing on Android device(5.0).

```
ComponentWillMount() {
    console.log('ComponentWillMount method');
}

ComponentDidMount() {
    console.log('ComponentDidMount method');
}


render() {
   console.log('In render method');

   return (
      <View>
      <Text> bla bla</Text>
      </View>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the React docs and their Specs, ComponentWillMount() is fired before the render() method, not after.

EDIT: Looks like a type, the name of function is "componentWillMount", not "ComponentWillMount".

Welcome to the JS world